# hotkey in datagrip to open a new console

Tags: datagrip

What is the hotkey in datagrip to open a new console and what is the hot key to close your current console. I did a google search and came up dry on this one. I would like to be able to do this to speed up my dev time by keeping my hand off the mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From 2021.1 the shortcut is `Cmd+Shift+L` or `Ctrl+Shift+Q`

Answer (score 4):

There is no hotkey for that. But you can assign yours!

For NEW CONSOLE:

1. Press `Ctrl(Cmd)+Shift+A`: *Find action*
2. Type "new console". You will see the action 'Open new console'
3. Press `Alt+Enter` to assign a shortcut
4. Assign it!

For CLOSE ACTIVE EDITOR:

1. Press `Ctrl(Cmd)+Shift+A`: *Find action*
2. Type "cae". You will see the action 'Close active editor'
3. Press `Alt+Enter` to assign a shortcut
4. Assign it!

Comment: Nice thanks. That answered the first part, but alas. `Ctrl+Shift+F4` does not close the current console

Comment: Sorry,  we need 'Close active Editor' action. I will update the answer.